# How to strip leading and trailing quote from string, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to strip leading and trailing quotes, in Ruby, from a string.  The quote character will occur 0 or 1 time.  For example, all of the following should be converted to foo,bar:

- `"foo,bar"`
- `"foo,bar`
- `foo,bar"`
- `foo,bar`

Comment: "[ask]" and "[mcve]" are good reading.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.5, reverse `chomp(x)` is available under the name `delete_prefix`, and `chomp(x)` is available as `delete_suffix`, meaning that you can use

```
'"foo,bar"'.delete_prefix('"').delete_suffix('"')
```

**OLD ANSWER**: For earlier Ruby versions, you could use the `chomp` function, but it unfortunately only works in the end of the string, assuming there was a reverse chomp, you could:

```
'"foo,bar"'.rchomp('"').chomp('"')
```

Implementing `rchomp` is straightforward:

```
class String
  def rchomp(sep = $/)
    self.start_with?(sep) ? self[sep.size..-1] : self
  end
end
```

Note that you could also do it inline, with the slightly less efficient version:

```
'"foo,bar"'.chomp('"').reverse.chomp('"').reverse
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  I expected someone to provide an answer involving array indices [0] and [-1], but had forgotten about chomp, an obviously better solution.  I think your answer is better than mine.

Comment: rchomp and lchomp should be required functions, damn it!

Comment: `delete_suffix` and `delete_prefix` methods are there, perhaps they were not present when this answer was written

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for pointing that out. I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 43):

I can use gsub to search for the leading or trailing quote and replace it with an empty string:

```
s = "\"foo,bar\""
s.gsub!(/^\"|\"?$/, '')
```

As suggested by comments below, a better solution is:

```
s.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
```

Comment: A couple of hints: there is no need to escape the quotes in the `Regexp`, since quotes don't have any special meaning in `Regexp` s anyway. Also, `^` and `$` *do not* anchor to the beginning and end of the *string*, they anchor to the beginning and end of the *line*. It's not clear from your question which one of the two you want: if you want to remove quotes from the beginning and end of the string, you need to use `\A` and `\Z` instead. Lastly, you can get rid of the escapes for the double quotes (and the confusing double double quotes) by delimiting your string with single quotes.

Comment: Altogether, it looks like this: ` s = '"foo,bar"'; s.gsub!(/\A"|\Z"$/, '') ` (I forgot: there's also no need to make the match optional. If it doesn't match, then simply nothing will get replaced.)

Comment: @Jörg, don't you mean `s.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')`?

Comment: @grddev: Yes, of course. This comment box makes a terrible IDE :-)

Answer (score 28):

As usual everyone grabs regex from the toolbox first. :-)

As an alternate I'll recommend looking into `.tr('"', '')` (AKA "translate") which, in this use, is really stripping the quotes.

Comment: Assuming there are no `"` in the middle of the string.

Comment: According to the examples given by the OP there are only leading/trailing double-quotes so it's a safe assumption.

Comment: It's not a safe assumption, but I didn't specifically state that there could be a quote inside the string.  Nevertheless, it's a good answer and one most definitely worth my +1.

Comment: <pedantry>He specified "a string".  Strings can contain arbitrary characters, including quotes.</pedantry>

Answer (score 10):

Another approach would be

```
remove_quotations('"foo,bar"')

def remove_quotations(str)
  if str.start_with?('"')
    str = str.slice(1..-1)
  end
  if str.end_with?('"')
    str = str.slice(0..-2)
  end
end
```

It is without RegExps and start_with?/end_with? are nicely readable.

Answer (score 4):

It frustrates me that strip only works on whitespace. I need to strip all kinds of characters! Here's a String extension that will fix that:

```
class String
  def trim sep=/\s/
    sep_source = sep.is_a?(Regexp) ? sep.source : Regexp.escape(sep)
    pattern = Regexp.new("\\A(#{sep_source})*(.*?)(#{sep_source})*\\z")
    self[pattern, 2]
  end
end
```

Output

```
'"foo,bar"'.trim '"'         # => "foo,bar"
'"foo,bar'.trim '"'          # => "foo,bar"
'foo,bar"'.trim '"'          # => "foo,bar"
'foo,bar'.trim '"'           # => "foo,bar"

'  foo,bar'.trim             # => "foo,bar"
'afoo,bare'.trim /[aeiou]/   # => "foo,bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that quotes can only appear at the beginning or end, you could just remove **all** quotes, without any custom method:

```
'"foo,bar"'.delete('"')
```

Comment: Any explanation on why this is being downvoted is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted the same but for slashes in url path, which can be `/test/test/test/` (so that it has the stripping characters in the middle) and eventually came up with something like this to avoid regexps:

```
'/test/test/test/'.split('/').reject(|i| i.empty?).join('/')
```

Which in this case translates obviously to:

```rb
 '"foo,bar"'.split('"').select{|i| i != ""}.join('"')
```

or

```
'"foo,bar"'.split('"').reject{|i| i.empty?}.join('"')
```

Comment: This question is seven and a half years old. Way to go, adding an answer with a new approach! Well worth my +1.

Answer (score 0):

Regexs can be pretty heavy and lead to some funky errors. If you are not dealing with massive strings and the data is pretty uniform you can use a simpler approach.

If you know the strings have starting and leading quotes you can splice the entire string:

```
string  = "'This has quotes!'"
trimmed = string[1..-2] 
puts trimmed # "This has quotes!"
```

This can also be turned into a simple function:

```
# In this case, 34 is \" and 39 is ', you can add other codes etc. 
def trim_chars(string, char_codes=[34, 39])
    if char_codes.include?(string[0]) && char_codes.include?(string[-1])
        string[1..-2]
    else
        string
    end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question posed.

Comment: Regexes do not lead to some funky errors. Bad code leads to some funky errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip non-optional quotes with `scan`:

```
'"foo"bar"'.scan(/"(.*)"/)[0][0]
# => "foo\"bar"
```

Comment: This fails for three of the examples given.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the quotes were optional in your case. This will be helpful for someone with slightly different requirements though.