# capture trailing whitespace in gherkin tables

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Let's say I have 2 scenarios like this:

```
Scenario: scenario 1
  Given foo
  When "meh"
  Then the output should be "hello"

Scenario: scenario 2
  Given foo
  When "blah"
  Then the output should be "hello "
```

And I try to convert them to a scenario outline like this

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given foo
  When <bar>
  Then the output should be <output_string>
  Examples:
  | bar | output_string |
  | meh | hello         |
  | blah| hello         |
```

Things fail, because gherkin table cells have their whitespace trimmed before processing. Is there any way to capture the trailing space that goes with the "hello" in the second example?

Answer (score 2):

Put the cell data in single quotes (or your preferred delimiter), and add a [`Transform`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Argument-Transforms) that will strip off the delimiters.

In `foo.feature`:

```
Scenario Outline:
Given foo
When <bar>
Then the output should be <output_string>
Examples:
| bar | output_string |
| meh | 'hello'       |
| blah| 'hello '      |
```

In `features/support/quoted_string_transform.rb`:

```
Transform /^'(.*)'$/ do |quoted_string|
  quoted_string
end
```

The transformation will apply to all matching captures, so choose your delimiters accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution would be to put the cell data in quotes:

```
Scenario Outline:
Given foo
When <bar>
Then the output should be <output_string>
Examples:
| bar | output_string |
| meh | "hello"       |
| blah| "hello "      |
```

Comment: Doesn't work - the double quotes get captured as part of the cell value. PS: My original post had a <bar> variable in the initial scenarios, which doesn't make sense. I suspect this made you transpose my table - bar and output_string are the placeholder variables, not bar, meh, and blah. I've edited my question to fix this.

Comment: The quotes might not be a big problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453262/how-to-strip-leading-and-trailing-quote-from-string-in-ruby

Comment: Not to be rude, but teaching me how to do basic string processing is not what I'm after here (my examples were simplified - I'm trying to use aruba steps, and don't really want to write my own steps with clunky work-arounds unless I have to). Ideally, there should be a way to escape leading/trailing whitespace in cuke tables to indicate that it's not to be cut off. I'd like someone to confirm that this does not exist prior to trying to hack around it.

Comment: And looking at the row parser spec (https://github.com/bryanl/gherkin/blob/master/spec/gherkin/shared/row_group.rb), it looks like there is no way to do this.