# Remove leading and trailing quotes from string if both are present

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I remove leading and trailing quotes from a string **only if both are present?** For example

```
"hello world" => hello world
"hello world => "hello world
hello world" => hello world"
```

I tried it with `gsub`, but the following removes every leading or trailing quotes, regardless if the other is present

```
'"hello world"'.gsub(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
# => this is ok it returns 'hello world'

'hello world"'.gsub(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
# => returns 'hello world' but should return 'hello world"'
```

Comment: While not a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3453262/128421 is very close and will give you ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
str.gsub(/\A"+(.*?)"+\Z/m, '\1')
```

The pattern will match a string starting with one or more `"`, then it can have any characters, any amount of them and then one or more double quotes at the end of the string. The whole string without the leading and trailing quotes will be inserted into the replacement result with the `\1` backreference.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/jKDyBl)

To only trim out the first and last double qoute, you may use

```
str.gsub(/\A"(.*)"\Z/m, '\1')
```

Comment: Isn't `"+` useless if `(.*)` is greedy? See: https://ideone.com/Ucu39f I'm pretty sure you want the lazy quantifier [`/\A"+(.*?)"+\Z/`](https://ideone.com/1typqr)..

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't think you want the `s` modifier on the end. In Ruby the `s` modifier indicates that the encoding of the regular expression is Windows-31J ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Encoding)).

Comment: @JoshCrozier: Yes, you are right as rain. I am in a rush and forgot that.

Comment: What would it look like, if I only want to remove one " at the beginning and end?

Comment: @23tux: Just remove the `+`s. Also, you may want to check for the very end of the string and use `\z` instead of a `\Z`. Use `.gsub(/\A"(.*)"\Z/m, '\1')` or `.gsub(/\A"(.*)"\z/m, '\1')` (updated the answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be more efficient than using a regex.

```
'"hello world'
.dup.tap{|s| s[0] = s[-1] = "" if s[0] == '"' and s[-1] == '"'}
# => "\"hello world"
'"hello world"'
.dup.tap{|s| s[0] = s[-1] = "" if s[0] == '"' and s[-1] == '"'}
# => "hello world"
'hello world"'
.dup.tap{|s| s[0] = s[-1] = "" if s[0] == '"' and s[-1] == '"'}
# => "hello world\""
```

Comment: I prefer the `gsub` solution, but upvoted since you're right that this is faster: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/a5f814c9a880960d0139

Answer (score 2):

Nice thing with ruby is that you can write code that reads like English in many cases. The good thing about it is that it is easy to understand.

```
x = '"hello world"'
quote = '"'

if x.start_with?(quote) && x.end_with?(quote)
  x = x[1...-1] 
end

puts x #=> hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother using a regex:

```
def strip_end_quotes(str)
  str[0] == '"' && str[-1] == '"' \
    ? str[1..-2] \
    : str
end

strip_end_quotes '"both"' # => "both"
strip_end_quotes '"left' # => "\"left"
strip_end_quotes 'right"' # => "right\""
```

Doing this in a single regex results in a pattern that isn't overly clear and clarity and readability is very important when coding. Being merciful to those who have to maintain the code in the future is good.