# How can I remove the first and last dash from a string?

Tags: regex, ruby

Let's say I have a string:

```
my_string = "-5-24-3-488-7--4-3-"
```

How can I remove **both** the first and the last dash? I want the result to look like this:

```
my_string = "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
```

I've thought about using `gsub`, or a regular expression, but I'm probably over-complicating the solution. Still I can't figure it out. Please Help.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455783/496676 then just replace the double quote with the dash.

Comment: It appears you want `my_string` to equal `"5-24-3-488-7--4-3"` after the operation, without changing `my_string`'s `object_id`, as opposed to creating a new string object. If so, you should clarify that you wish to modify `my_string` *in place* (no change to `object_id`) and that it's value should become `"5-24-3-488-7--4-3"` (`my_string =...` is confusing).

Comment: I want the result to look like this: `"5-24-3-488-7--4-3"` I edited the question. I hope that clarifies things @cary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex `^-|-$` matches a hyphen at the beginning, or a hyphen at the end.

In Ruby:

```
"-5-24-3-488-7--4-3-".gsub(/^-|-$/, '')
```

And if you want to modify the string in-place,

```
my_string.gsub!(/^-|-$/, '')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
my_string.delete_prefix("-").delete_suffix("-")
# => "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
```

Answer (score 2):

In view of the other answers given to this question, my answer may in part illustrate the importance of providing a complete and unambiguous statement of a question.

```
def remove_first_and_last_hyphen(str)
  idx = str.index('-')
  if idx
    str[idx] = ''
    idx = str.rindex('-')
    str[idx] = '' if idx
  end
  str
end

str = "-5-24-3-488-7--4-3-"
remove_first_and_last_hyphen str
  #=> "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
str
  #=> "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
remove_first_and_last_hyphen "5-24-3-488-7--4-3-"
  #=> "524-3-488-7--4-3"
remove_first_and_last_hyphen "-5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
  #=> "5-24-3-488-7--43"
remove_first_and_last_hyphen "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
  #=> "524-3-488-7--43"
```

I defined `str` in the first example to show that `str` was mutated (modified).

The question is, "How can I remove the first and last dash from a string?". An example is given, but it shows only what is wanted in a particular case, and is consistent with various interpretations of the question.

Aside from the confusion between dashes and hyphens, there is only one way to interpret "the first and last hyphen from a string"; namely, the hyphen having the smallest index (if the string contains at least one hyphen) and the hyphen having the largest string index (if the string contains at least two hyphens). That is of course not the same as "the first and last characters of a string, provided they are hyphens". The OP may have something different in mind, but I can only go by what is asked in such a clear and unambiguous way.

By "remove" in "...remove the first and last", I assume the OP wishes to modify the string in place, as opposed to returning a new string. If I am wrong about that my code would have to be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `-` at the beginning and the end, then you can do:

```
"-5-24-3-488-7--4-3-"[1..-2]
# => "5-24-3-488-7--4-3"
```

Comment: And what if they're optional?

Comment: The OP may wish to modify the string in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try `my_string.scan(/\A-(.+)-\z/).flatten.first`. The `\A` and `\z` match the beginning and end of the string.